# BINDで名前解決(正引き)ができない

Tags: dns

BINDで名前解決(正引き)ができません。
どの様にアプローチして問題を解決すればよいのか教えて頂いてもよろしいでしょうか。

下記に私が設定した内容を記載します。

`/etc/named/local.zone`の設定

```
zone "unk.unk" IN { 
    type master;
    file "test.db";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.db";
};
```

`/var/named/test.db`の内容

```
@         IN       SOA     ns.test01.com.  root.webtest01.com.(
                                        2015123105 ; Serial
                                        28800      ; Refresh
                                        14400      ; Retry
                                        3600000    ; Expire
                                        86400 )    ; Minimum
          IN NS    ns.test01.com.
localhost IN A     172.0.0.1
pc01      IN A     192.168.0.100
pc02      IN A     192.168.0.200
```

`ping`の結果

```
# ping pc01.test01.com
ping: pc01.test01.com: 名前またはサービスが不明です
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

起動時に何らか警告メッセージなど出力されていませんか？

```
zone "unk.unk" IN { 
    type master;
    file "test.db";
};
```

は`unk.unk`ドメイン、`*.unk.unk`サブドメインに対する応答を定義するエントリです。この中で`test01.com`に関するエントリを用意しても無意味です。

```
zone "test01.com" IN { 
    type master;
    file "test.db";
};
```

になるべきです。
次に

```
 IN NS    ns.test01.com.
```

とあるのでクライアントは`ns.test01.com`に続きを尋ねることになります。`ns.test01.com`のアドレスを用意する必要がありますが、それがありません。

なお、`test01.com`はGoDaddy.com, LLCの所有するドメインです。質問者さんはこちらの関係者でしょうか？ 無関係であれば、`example.com`等を使用するべきです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。`test01.com`は適当につけた名前だったので修正します。